# How can I add title on seaborn lmplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to add title on Searbon lmplot.

```
ax = plt.axes()
sns.lmplot(x, y, data=df, hue="hue", ax=ax)
ax.set_title("Graph (a)")
plt.show()
```

But I noticed that `lmplot` does not have an `ax` parameter.
How can I add a title on my lmplot?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @Akash lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax'.

Comment: @jaykodeveloper, do you want to set a common title or one title for each subplot?

Comment: lmplots do not accept ax arguments as they return facetgrids not subplots. generally i just add `plt.title("your title")`

Comment: @WoodyPride it generates another empty graph. Thank you though

Comment: Hmmm.. not in my environment. strange

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
sns.lmplot(x, y, data=df, hue="hue")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_title("Graph (a)")
```

Comment: This generates an empty plot with the title; the lmplot is still untitled.

Answer (score 12):

```
# Create lmplot
lm = sns.lmplot(x, y, data=df, hue="hue", ax=ax)

# Access the figure
fig = lm.fig 

# Add a title to the Figure
fig.suptitle("My figtitle", fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 10):

`seaborn` uses `matplotlib` under the hood, so if you want a simple answer, use:

```
plt.title('My Title')
```

Right before

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sns.lmplot(x, y, data=df, hue="hue", ax=ax).fig.suptitle("Graph (a)")
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!