# Adding a subtitle to seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I have the following Seaborn FacetGrid plot using `sns.lmplot()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from palmerpenguins import load_penguins
df = load_penguins()

g = sns.lmplot(
    data=df, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm",
    col="species", row="sex", height=3,
)

plt.show()
```

[image: lmplot example]

How can I include a title **and** subtitle for the entire figure? Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813694/how-to-add-a-title-to-seaborn-facet-plot) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307941/how-can-i-add-title-on-seaborn-lmplot) I know I can add a title by including something like this:

```
g.fig.suptitle("Palmer's Penguins", x = 0.5, y = 1.1, fontsize = 16)
```

[image: lmplot example with title]

But neither of these questions address how to include a subtitle in addition to the title. If possible, I would prefer to stick with an object-oriented approach (for example, if there were something like `g.fig.subtitle()`) as opposed to a more generalized PyPlot approach (like something that might use `plt.title()`).

Comment: There is a y-value for height adjustment in the title settings already set up, so I think that would be the best choice. `g.fig.suptitle("Palmer's Penguins", x=0.5, y= 1.05, fontsize=16)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `g.fig.text()` to manually add a subtitle:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from palmerpenguins import load_penguins
df = load_penguins()

g = sns.lmplot(
    data=df, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm",
    col="species", row="sex", height=3,
)

g.fig.suptitle("Palmer's Penguins", x = 0.5, y = 1.1, fontsize = 16)
g.fig.text(x=0.435, y=1.025, s="This is a subtitle")

plt.show()
```

[image: lmplot example with title and subtitle]

It takes some adjusting to the `x` and `y` arguments to center it as desired, but this seems to be the best option available and it does the trick.

Comment: You can put at 0.5, 1.025 and set `horizontalalignment='center'`